# Pegar valor de ID e colocar dentro do campo hidden

Tags: javascript

Colegas.

Estou pegando através do Javascript o valor de um resultado e colocando dentro de um ID:

```
document.getElementById("ValorUnitarioTriplo").innerHTML = " USD "+triplo.toFixed(2)+"";
...............
<div id="ValorUnitarioTriplo">USD 0.00</div>
```

Legal. Funciona. Porém gostaria de que esse valor ficasse dentro do value de um input hidden. É possível fazer isso? Dessa forma mando para o banco de dados usando o PHP e Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É basicamente da forma que você já está fazendo.

Digamos que você já tem o `input`, basta buscar pelo **id** e setar o valor. Ficaria assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="txtValor" id="txtValor" value="">
--
document.getElementById("txtValor").value = "1";
```

```js
document.getElementById("txtValor").value = "1";
alert('Valor do input:' + document.getElementById("txtValor").value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="txtValor" id="txtValor" value="">
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos. Só mais uma pergunta. Como eu faria para pegar esse valor que pegamos do javascript e colocasse dentro de uma variável em PHP. Ex.: $valor = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'nome_do_campo_value');

Comment: @Jose.Marcos Se você observar o `input` possui um **name** (txtValor). Utilize ele em seu post para pegar o valor. Algo tipo assim: `$valor = $_POST["txtValor"];`

Comment: Desculpe Randrade. Acho que não fui claro na minha dúvida. No seu código o value aparece vazio. <input type="hidden" name="checkyear" id="txtValor" value="">. Foi aí que gerou minha dúvida.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos Ele não aparece o `value` no html. Mas se você inspecionar o elemento (F12), ele estará lá.

Comment: Entendi. Perfeito. Obrigado Randrade.

Answer (score 2):

É só fazeres da mesma maneira, usando o ID de um input que cries, e usando `.value` em vez de `.innerHTML`:

```
function gravar(id, val){
    var valor = " USD " + val.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = valor;
    document.getElementById('input_' + id).value = valor;
}
```

E tendo o HTML

```
<div id="ValorUnitarioTriplo">USD 0.00</div>
<input type="hidden" name="vut" id="input_ValorUnitarioTriplo" />
```

Podes usar no JS assim:

```
gravar('ValorUnitarioTriplo', 456.7879);
```

Não te esqueças de dar atributo `name` ao *input*  para o servidor ir buscar o valor.

Comment: Faltaram as aspas, eu receio: `gravar("ValorUnitarioTriplo"`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown exato, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Evidente! As pessoas fazem isso o tempo todo:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="x" id="hidden-field">
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("hidden-field").value = "seu valor";
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$("#hidden-field").val("seu valor");
```

Answer (score 0):

Estive com o mesmo problema e fiz conforme o código abaixo
na controller  fiz um método  pra retorna uma lista da busca em Json

```
 public JsonResult BuscaNomePaciente(string text)
      {
       var list = PRep.Lista().Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(text)).Select(c => 
        new { ID = c.ID, Nome = c.Nome }); 
           return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
       }
```

No View Create foi implementado este trecho de codigo a baixo:

```
//Referência das bibliotecas Jquery, Jequery ui
<link href="~/Content/themes/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_Paciente, htmlAttributes: new { @class 
 = "control-label" })
    <input type="text" id="busca" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca 
Paciente" />
    <input type="text" id="hidden-Nome" name="Id_Paciente" />
</div>

<script>
   $("#busca").autocomplete({

          source: function (request, response) {
           var text = $("#busca").val();
              $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
               url: "/Paciente/BuscaNomePaciente",
               dataType: "Json",
               data: { text: $("#busca").val() },
               success: function (data) {  

                response($.map(data, function (item) { 
                    return { label: item.Nome, value: item.ID }; // e
```

retornado dois valores Nome, e o ID do meu controle 
                       }));
                   }

```
           })

       },
       minLength: 2, // Busca a partir de 4 caractere digitado no campo
        delay: 100,
        select: function (event, ui) {

            alert("ID do Nome Selecionado :" + ui.item.value)

            $("#hidden-Nome").val(ui.item.value);  //  obtem o id da do Paciente 
selecionada e adicioná-lo no input #hidden-Nome   

    }
});

</script>
```